# Resize/Create a New Partition in GParted

Tags: partitioning, windows, ntfs, gparted

So I've been having some trouble recently with Ubuntu and decided it was time to switch to windows. But I have no ntfs partitions on my hard disk and GParted will not let me resize my one large partition (/dev/sda1) so that I can allocate some ntfs space to install windows on.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've had this problem for quite some time now and it had just become one big headache.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You can not resize a partition when it is in use. Boot a live CD, make sure the partition is not mounted, and run gparted from there.

Make sure the swap partition is not mounted either (swapoff).

You can mount / unmount a partition from gparted as well.

Comment: so I unmount it before I boot off the live cd?

Comment: No, just boot a live CD and unmount sway or your hard drive if they were automatically mounted (ubuntu tends to mount any swap partitions it finds). The gparted live CD is a nice tool as it is a smaller download and does not auto mount partitions.